# Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{k=1}^{n} (1-e^{-ka})$ exists an is positive

Tags: calculus, limits, infinite-product

If $a$ is a positive constant,then show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{k=1}^{n} (1-e^{-ka})$ exists and is strictly positive.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your question is a product of the form $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\prod_{k=1}^n (1 - e^{-ka})$.

Any product of the form $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\prod_{k=1}^n (1 - a_k)$ converges iff $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ converges.

In your cases, $a_k = e^{-ka}$.

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n  a_k = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-ka}$ converges to $\frac{1}{e^a-1}$ $(\text{geometric series with }e^{-a}<1\text{ as }a>0)$.

Hence, the infinite product $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\prod_{k=1}^n (1 - e^{-ka})$ converges.

**EDIT**

The equivalence of the convergence of $\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 + a_n)$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$.

Assume that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges. This implies $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$. Hence, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log(1+a_n)}{a_n} = 1$.

Now consider $b_n = \log(1+a_n)$. By limit comparison test, since $0<\frac{b_n}{a_n}<\infty$, we have that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges. (Intuitively, what the limit comparison test means is that the tail sums differ only by a factor and hence the convergence of one implies the other.)

Hence, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log(1+a_n)$ converges which essentially means $\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ converges.

Similarly, you can argue out that if $\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ converges, then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.

Comment: +1.  It is not every day that I see the Cauchy root test cited to justify convergence of a geometric series.

Comment: @Jonas: oops... I was stuck with Cauchy root test since I used it to prove couple of convergences yesterday. Interesting how mind sticks on to a particular mode of thinking. I have now deleted it since Cauchy root test is derived from geometric series and hence I think using the geometric series would be a cleaner argument.

Comment: Sivaram, could you go a little bit further into depth with line #2 please? I understand your reasoning, intuitively, that if those sums converge, then summing up the permuted products of things going rapidly to zero will doubtless converge, but I don't think I understand why the reverse implication holds and it would help me to see some manipulation.

Comment: @Billare: The reason why the convergence of the product is equivalent to the convergence of the sum is due to the limit comparison test. I shall update my post to explain this in detail.

Comment: @Sivaram, I'm sure I'm being dense, but where in your argument does it explicitly show that the limit is *strictly* positive?

Comment: @cardinal: Good point. I didn't notice it. But the convergence of the sum $|a_n|$ also implies the product is non-zero, since for large $n$, $|log(1+a_n)| < |a_n|$, and hence the sum of the logs dont blow up to $-\infty$ either. I will clear it up in the post. Thanks

Comment: @Sivaram, I hope you don't mind. I've provided an alternate argument and explicitly calculated a bound, similar to the method you suggest.

Comment: @cardinal: No problem at all.

Comment: @Sivaram, also note that for $-1 < x < 0$, it is never true that $|\log(1+x)| < |x|$.

Comment: @cardinal: Yup. I missed it in the previous comment. Your argument carries through.

Comment: @Sivaram, sorry to be so pedantic. But I don't believe $\sum |a_n| < \infty$ is necessary for convergence here. Indeed, let $a_n = 1/(n+1)$, or more extreme yet, let it be $a_n = 1/n$.

Comment: @cardinal: If I am right, if none of the terms in the product are zero and if $\sum a_n$ converges, then the product also converges to a strictly positive number.

Comment: @Sivaram, *that* does sound likely to me, provided, of course that $a_n < 1$. The version that I have normally seen of the "theorem" given in your answer takes $a_n \leq 0$.

Comment: @cardinal: I don't completely understand what you are saying. Isn't that what I have proved in the above argument? $\sum{\log{(1+a_n)}}$ converges also implies the product doesn't go to zero?

Comment: @Sivaram, I think part of the confusion we may be having in communicating is that in one case we consider $\prod (1-a_n)$ and in another $\prod (1+a_n)$. I've been thinking in terms of the former of the two. :)

Comment: @cardinal: Oh Ok. But in that case still, replace $a_n$ by $-a_n$ and the argument will stil carry through right? since $\sum a_n$ converges, then so does $\sum (-a_n)$

Comment: @Sivaram, my point, stated rather ineloquently, was that it is not true in general that $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum a_n$ converges. A previous comment provides a counterexample. However, if $-1 < a_n \leq 0$, then $\prod (1+a_n)$ has a nonzero (i.e., strictly positive) limit if and only if $\sum a_n$ has a finite limit. The latter *does* follow essentially from your argument.

Comment: @cardinal: If I am right, your argument is if $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$, then the product $\prod(1-a_n)$ is $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{3}{4} \times \ldots = 0$, whereas $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges. (Note $\prod(1+a_n)$ diverges.) So If I were to state it as follows: If none of the terms in the product are zero, then $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges to a $\textbf{strictly positive number}$. Sorry if I sound confusing.

Comment: @Sivaram, no. I believe the signs of the $a_n$ are (also) important. For example, let $a_{2n-1} = e^{1/\log (n+1)} - 1$ and $a_{2n} = e^{-1/\log (n+1)} - 1$. Then $\prod (1+a_n) = 1$ and $\sum a_n$ does not converge since $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} a_k = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} (e^{1/\log k} + e^{-1 / \log k} - 2) \geq n (e^{1/\log(n+1)} + e^{-1/\log(n+1)} - 2) \to \infty$. Correct?

Comment: @cardinal: Ok. I see. But where is the flaw in my proof and how do I correct it. Feel free to edit my post.

Comment: @Sivaram, hmm, not sure I feel too comfortable about that. I'll think about it and if I can come up with a set of very minimal edits, then I'll do that. After "**EDIT**", mostly, I think you need to restrict the $a_n$ to fall in $(-1,0]$ and also add in the qualifier that the limit is strictly positive if and only if $\sum a_n$ is finite by your argument. (But, the fact that the product converges does not imply the sum does, since the product can converge to zero while the sum diverges.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly different argument than @Sivaram's answer. I'm not sure his makes explicit (or even proves) that the limit is *strictly positive*, as requested.

First note that if $a > 0$, then $0 < 1 - e^{-an} < 1$ for all $n$ and so the "partial product"

$$
P_n = \prod_{k=1}^n (1 - e^{-a k})
$$

is decreasing and bounded below. The fact that $\lim_n\, P_n$ ***exists*** follows immediately.

To show that the limit is strictly positive, note that for all $n \geq \frac{1}{a} \log 2$, we have that $e^{-a n} \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Let $N(a) \equiv N = \lceil \frac{1}{a} \log 2\rceil$.

Since for $0 \leq x \leq 1/2$, $\log(1-x) \geq - x - x^2$, we get that
$$
\prod_{n=N}^\infty (1 - e^{-a n}) = \exp\big( \sum_{n=N}^\infty \log(1-e^{-an}) \big) \geq \exp( -\sum_{n=N}^\infty (e^{-an}+e^{-2an}) ) \geq \exp( - 2\sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{-an} ) .
$$

Now, $\sum_{n=N}^\infty \,e^{-a n} \leq \frac{1}{1-e^{-a}}$ and so
$$
\lim_n \, P_n = P_{N-1} \prod_{m=N}^\infty (1 - e^{-a m}) \geq e^{-2/(1-e^{-a})} P_{N-1} > 0 .
$$

Comment: You mean "bounded above" in the your answer, right?

Comment: @Billare, well $P_n$ is both bounded from above and bounded from below. **but** the important one in terms of quickly establishing that the limit exists is that it is bounded from below, as originally stated. Hope that helps.